# Google chrome web developer tool

Tags: google-chrome, javascript-debugger, google-developer-tools

For some time, the web developer tools of chrome is very slow.
When I navigate in tabs, or when I debug.

But the navigation in the browser is fine, I try to remove all extensions, I reinstall Chrome, but nothing change...

Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

Did you ever see a problem like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sometimes debugger crushes, but in my case is because I save a 64base image into a String variable in javascript while I'm debugging.

I recommend you to use "Firefox developer edition" or "Firefox".

Comment: So I have to give up Chrome ?

Comment: I have installed Firefox and Chrome, and Firefox developer tools work better than Chrome's tools, but it's my opinion.
I have Chrome at version is 52.0.2743.116 m (64 bits)

Comment: With Firefox Debugger it's fine but I miss Chrome Debugger... I think it's because of my ASP .Net configuration or IIS (I don't know)

Comment: I don't know, I'm using Node.js (server) and angular.js (client). I can't help more